# Panda DataFrame Combine Unique Values in Two Column for OrdinalEncoder Fit

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have Titanic dataset and columns in a dataframe I would like to use are 'Embarked' and 'Sex'.

`df['Embarked']` and `df['Sex']` have Unique value: `Embarked['C','Q','S']` and `Sex['male','female']`

What I would like to do is create a list like below:

```
[['S','female'],['S','male'],['C','female'],['c','male'],['Q','female'],['Q','male']]
```

I need unique value combination in a list format so that I can pass to `OrdinalEncoder` to fit.

Scikit Learn `OrdinalEncoder` example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)

enc.categories_

enc.transform([['Female', 3], ['Male', 1],['Female',2],['Male',3]])
```

encoder transform only takes `list`

Comment: it is not clear what your question is, can you provide more detail? for example, desired output given your sample input

Comment: Are you trying to have an ordinal variable representing all Embarked × Sex pairwise conjunctions?

Comment: Hi Igor, that's right!

Comment: Hi Yuca, I would like to have the combination of unique value of two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you'd like is to find the product from the unique values of two columns in a dataframe then turn them into a list, then this will do that!

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

data = pd.DataFrame([['Q', 'male'], ['Q', 'male'], ['S', 'female'], 
                     ['S', 'female'], ['S', 'male'], ['C', 'female'], 
                     ['C', 'female'], ['C', 'male'], ['C', 'male']],
                    columns=['Embarked', 'Sex'])

print([list(x) for x in product(data['Embarked'].unique(), data['Sex'].unique())])
```

`itertools.product` gives you the Cartesian Product of a sequence of iterables.  Our iterables here are lists created by calling `Series.unique()` on each of the DataFrame's columns to get their unique values.

Finally, the `list comprehension` turns `itertools.product`'s typical return of a list of tuples into a list of lists.

Comment: Is there any automate way instead of manually put data in the dataframe?

Comment: yea, this was just giving you a repeatable example.  you can read in a .csv as a dataframe doing `pd.read_csv(filepath)`.

Answer (score 0):

a way of doing it is:

```
list_1 = ['C','Q','S']
list_2 = ['male','female']
X = [[x, y] for x in list_1 for y in list_2]
```